# fill na with group by that label's median number

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, feature-engineering

Let say I have

```
v1  v2 v3  label 

3   Nan      1
4    2       2
3    3       2 
2    4       1
4    5       1
```

I want to fill the v2 Nan with target label(1)'s medium.

so it will be   4+5 //2 = 4.5

```
grouped = train[['V0005','label']].groupby('label') 
train[na_list[0]] = train[na_list[0]].fillna(grouped[na_list[0]].median())[targetlabel]
```

stucked in here

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
#if necessary convert to numeric
train = train.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
```

---

```
train = train.fillna(train.groupby('label').transform('median'))
print (train)
   v1   v2  label
0   3  4.5      1
1   4  2.0      2
2   3  3.0      2
3   2  4.0      1
4   4  5.0      1
```

If want specify only some columns for replace:

```
cols = ['v2']
train[cols] = train[cols].fillna(train.groupby('label')[cols].transform('median'))
print (train)
```